# How to create a colorbox that looks like "example" section in textbooks?

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed

I'd like to create a `tcolorbox` that looks like "example" sections in many textbooks, for example, something like the attached screenshot.

[image: n]

I found one sample code from an [online source](https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/a-simple-latex-example-environment/), which uses `mdframed`. Yet I'd like to include as less packages as possible, thus wondering if there is ways to rewrite using `tcolorbox`. Thank you!

The sample code is:

```
\newlength{\framedinnerleftmargin}
\newlength{\framedinnertopmargin}
\newlength{\framedreversedinnerleftmargin}
\setlength{\framedinnerleftmargin}{\widthof{Theoreme 10.10.10}+2em}
\setlength{\framedreversedinnerleftmargin}{\widthof{Theoreme 10.10.10}+1em}
\setlength{\framedinnertopmargin}{1em}

% first argument: label in upper left corner,
% second argument: background color
\newenvironment{boxedtext}[2]{\begin{mdframed}[%
hidealllines=true,%
backgroundcolor=#2,%
innertopmargin=\framedinnertopmargin,%
innerleftmargin=\framedinnerleftmargin,%
innerrightmargin=1em%
]%
\tabto{-\framedreversedinnerleftmargin}\textbf{#1}\tabto*{0em}%
}% begin code
{\hskip 0pt\\\hspace*{\fill}\end{mdframed}\vspace{1em}} % end code

\newenvironment{summary}[0]{\begin{center}\begin{minipage}[c]{\summarywidth}\begin{spacing}{0.9}\footnotesize} % begin code
{\end{spacing}\end{minipage}\end{center}} % end code

\newcounter{question}

% optional! if you want it to start at zero
% with every new chapter/section/etc.
\numberwithin{question}{section}

\newenvironment{question}[0]
{\refstepcounter{question}\vspace{1em plus 1em}\begin{boxedtext}{Question \thequestion.}{blue!7}}%\setlength{\parskip}{0em}}
{\end{boxedtext}\vspace{-1em plus 1em}}

\newenvironment{question*}[0]
{\vspace{1em plus 1em}\begin{boxedtext}{Question.}{blue!7}}
{\end{boxedtext}\vspace{-1em plus 1em}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something to start with. Refer to the documentation of `tcolorbox` for more customisation.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{myexample}[2][]{%
    coltitle=black,
    title={{\bfseries Example~\thetcbcounter.}\quad#2},
    colback=black!5,
    colframe=black!10,
    coltext=blue,
    #1
}

\begin{myexample}[]{Example Title}
    Content. \blindtext[1]
\end{myexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]